# Sonar pull request analysis is scanning entire repo instead of just the changed files in gerrit git

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-gerrit

Helllo,
we have enterirpise SQ setup on premis and it is setup to do Sonar Gerrit

but we are observing that scan is taking long to complete as it is running on entire repo and not JUST scanning the changed files. any guidance how can we avoid delay of scanning unnecessary entire repo?
we just want only changed files to be scanned that are part of patchset in gerrit.

```
sonar.host.url=http://sonar.team.com:9000

sonar.login=${env.SONAR_TOKEN}
sonar.projectKey=Services
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.test.inclusions=src/**/test/**/*
# Exclude test subdirectories from source scope
sonar.exclusions=src/**/test/*,src/**/test/**/*,src/**/**/*.tf
sonar.c.file.suffixes=-
sonar.cpp.file.suffixes=-
sonar.objc.file.suffixes=-
```

```
    sonar-scanner -X \
        -Dsonar.pullrequest.key="${GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER}-${GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER}" \
        -Dsonar.pullrequest.base="${GERRIT_BRANCH}" \
        -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch="${GERRIT_REFSPEC}" \
        -Dsonar.src="src/services/test_ps_scan/" \
        -Dsonar.exclusions=**/*.tf,src/**/test/*,src/**/test/**/*,src/**/**/*.tf
```

logs

```
Issues to be commented: 0
Issues to be involved in score calculation: 0
Review has been sent
```

Jenkinsfile

```
                        withSonarQubeEnv('sonar.team.com') {
                            sh '''
                            src/jenkins/ci/pba.sh
                            '''.stripIndent()
                        }
                        sonarToGerrit(
                            inspectionConfig: [
                                    analysisStrategy: pullRequest()
                            ],
```

change files on gerrit are under this path
/src/jenkins/ci/ and scan is scanning all files undre /src/* any hint why ?

Comment: Since you did not specify `sonar.sources`, it will find and scan all the files from the current working directory.

Comment: that is right. shall i close my question?